# Conditional color of points depending on which variable takes a specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following df

```
library(Rlab)    
    
q <- data.frame(v = seq(1,1000,1), w = round(rnorm(1000,500,200),2),
                    x = rbern(1000, 0.1),y = rbern(1000, 0.1), z = rbern(1000, 0.1))
```

When x = 1, I would like to plot 'w' on the graph with a color (say blue). When y = 1, I would like to plot 'w' on the graph with a color (say red). When z = 1, I would like to plot 'w' on the graph with a color (say green). When x,y,or z = 0, then I need no points. In case they overlap, I would like a dodge (but not necessary...)

How can I do that using ggplot2? notably with geom_point?

I tried the following for just one 'x' but it plots both the 1 and 0.

```
ggplot(q , aes (v,w,color = x))+geom_point()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, if I replace x,y,z by x * w, x * y , x * z , and the do q[q==0]<-NA , I can plot the usual way... still on the market for a better, more r solution in case someone has it. Else will close question in 1 day.

Comment: @tjebo from package "RLab"... have edited question to mention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to reshape (melt) the dataset first, otherwise you won't see the points with multiple colours.  From your description you want multiple points when say `x` and `y` are both 1.

Reshaping to a long form (or `melt`ing in data.table language) will create three rows for each of your rows, one each for `x`, `y` and `z`.  Then you can select only those rows where the `value` is 1 (the points you want to show).  The `variable` factor corresponds to `x`, `y`, or `z` so now it is easy to set the colours and the dodge that you want.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(q)

qlong <- melt(q, id.vars = c("v","w"))[value==1]

ggplot(qlong, aes(v,w,group=variable,color=variable)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge2(width = .2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i have added more explanation

Answer (score 2):

You could use `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

q <- q %>%   mutate(color = factor(case_when(
    x == 1 ~ "blue",
    y == 1 ~ "red",
    z == 1 ~ "green"), levels=c("blue","green","red")))
  
ggplot(q[!is.na(q$color),])+
  geom_point(aes(x=v,y=w,color=color))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","green","red"))
```

Comment: see edit to make sure factor corresponds to color